# Update query from select by specific paramethers

Tags: mysql

I try to update all values in table by specific parameter with one mysql query
i have this structure:

```
seller_id | product | value 
1 | apple | 100
1 | onion | 50
1 | cherry | 20
1 | lemon | 200
2 | apple | 10
2 | onion | 40
2 | lemon | 100
3 | apple | 10
3 | lemon | 50
3 | orange | 140
```

normally i use several queries for update: one select and several update, bu i want to make just one query for better performance in big database

```
SELECT `product` FROM table WHERE seller_id = '1' AND `value` > '0'

while($r = mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
   $list[] = $r['0'];
}

foreach($list as $k => $i)
{
   UPDATE `table` SET `value`='100' WHERE product = '$i'
    // updated: apple:100; onion:100; cherry:100; lemon:100; for all seller which have it
}
```

I try to make one query from this, i need to get all products in storage of seller:1 and update some value in all seller witch have this product

I try something like this but its not work
(#1093 - You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause)

```
UPDATE table SET value='100' WHERE product = 
  (SELECT `product` FROM table WHERE seller_id = '1')
```

I need more performance and i don't want use PHP to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83743/2/0)

```
UPDATE tab_name AS t1
  INNER JOIN tab_name AS t2 ON t1.product = t2.product
    SET t1.value = 100
    WHERE t2.seller_id = 1;
```

Comment: But the OP is expecting to update all products that the `seller_id = 1` has in the rest of the `seller_id`

Comment: @MostyMostacho is this query not sufficient :(

Comment: No, because OP wants to update `apple, onion, cherry` in the whole table

Comment: @AragoN Pleasure help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to give new alias to your subselect or other way directly put the where condition

```
UPDATE table SET value='100' WHERE product IN(
 SELECT t.`product` FROM  (SELECT `product` FROM table WHERE seller_id = '1') t )
```

Comment: My only concern with this is that it tends to be VERY slow. Maybe the way the OP is doing it right now is faster. BTW, I usually solve this issues in this way too.

Comment: @MostyMostacho As approach of OP he will always get *You can't specify target table 'table'* because its true in subselect with update you can't specify the same table you need give new alias to the subselect in order to sort this out

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
UPDATE table1 AS a
INNER JOIN table1 AS b ON b.product = a.product
SET a.value = 100
WHERE  b.seller_id = 1;
```

It will JOIN by product and update where seller_id = 1.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c253e/2)</kbd>